# Attempted Proof of a Theorem on Nested Intervals

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the *Nested Interval Theorem*, which is:

> Given nested closed intervals of Real Numbers
>   $$[a_1,b_1]\supset[a_2,b_2]\supset\cdots\supset[a_n,b_n]\supset\cdots$$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n-b_n|=0$,
>   there exists an element $x_0\in \bigcap_{i=1}^\infty [a_i,b_i]$ and $x_0$ is unique.

I think my proof is wrong somewhere. Could anybody tell me where the mistake is?

**Proof:** (By contradiction.)
Suppose $\cap[a_n,b_n]=\varnothing$, then $\exists n_1,n_2$ ($n_2>n_1$), such that $[a_{n_1},b_{n_1}]\cap[a_{n_2},b_{n_2}]=\varnothing$, but $[a_{n_1},b_{n_1}]\supset [a_{n_2},b_{n_2}]$ and $b_{n_2}-a_{n_2}\neq0$, contradiction.

Comment: I think for the statement you're proving, that you want to add that $a_n \rightarrow c$ and $b_n \rightarrow c$ for some real number $c$?

Comment: There is another statement: $lim_{n->\infty}|b_n-a_n|=0$. sorry for forgetting it.

Answer (score 0):

The statement fails to be true. Take $I_n=[-1-1/n, 1+1/n]$ for $n\in \mathbf{N}_{\ge 1}$. $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty I_n=[-1,1].$ This set contains infinitely many elements.

Your proof does not address the statement, because you are trying to show existence of an element in the intersection without uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Given your setup $[a_1,b_1]\supset[a_2,b_2]\supset ...\supset[a_n,b_n]\supset...\Rightarrow \exists x_0\in \cap[a_n,b_n]$ and $x_0$ is unique.

Your conclusion is too strong. Take, for example, $a_n=2,$ and $b_n=3+\frac{1}{n}.$ Then 
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty ~[a_i,b_i]=[2,3].$$

Plianly, there is no unique $x\in[2,3].$